HTTPS Requests Work in Flutter During Development andorid studio but Fail in Internal Testing on Google Play
I am new to the topic of uploading a flutter app to Google Play Console and I get the following problem: when I run my app in Android Studio, https works correctly, but when I upload my app to internal tests in Google Play Console, it doesn't work.
I upload a bundle file to google play console
What could be the problem? Any configuration in flutter or google play console?
Do I need to give any other information?
Thank you very much for your help

Did you add the line
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

in your AndroidManifest.xml file?
